# Adding Lightbox to an unsupported theme in Wordpress 3.0.1

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, lightbox2

Has anyone discovered a relatively easy way to add lightbox to a theme that doesn't support it out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for viewing, but I figured it out.  `<?php wp_head(); ?>` was in `header.php`, but in the wrong place for some reason.